# How to disable RBF in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, replace-by-fee, createrawtransaction

I am creating a transaction with Bitcoin Core (v24.0.1) and it has RBF enabled (sequence: 4294967293) by default. I am trying to disable RBF by adding `walletrbf=0` and `mempoolfullrbf=0` to bitcoin.conf but it does not seem to make any difference to the input's sequence field.

EDIT:
I use `bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction` to create the transaction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`walletrbf=0` only disables RBF when creating transactions through wallet RPCs such as `sendtoaddress`, `sendmany` or `sendall`. If you use the low-level RPC `createrawtransaction`, you need to either set the `replaceable` parameter to false or manually set your sequence numbers. If you're creating transactions through the Send tab in the GUI, you simply need to uncheck a checkbox right below fee selection that says "Enable Replace-By-Fee".

`mempoolfullrbf=0` controls a mempool policy (whether to allow replacements for transactions that don't signal RBF), it has nothing to do with the wallet, and it's currently off by default which means this line in bitcoin.conf isn't actually doing anything.